# Calculating Maximum a posteriori (MAP) for classifier

Tags: derivatives, optimization, logarithms, machine-learning

Given is a probability function for class y, together with a prior for weights w (samples are assumed to be i.i.d, and b is a positive scalar, Z ensures normalization):

$P(y | \textbf{x,w}) = \frac{1}{1+exp(-y \textbf{w}^T \textbf{x})}$

$P(\textbf{w};b) = \frac{1}{Z}*exp(\frac{-\sum_{i}^dw_i^4}{b})$

We have to **find the MAP** for $\prod_{i}^n P(y_i | \textbf{x_i,w})*P(\textbf{w};b)$

I would solve this like a Maximum Likelihood optimization problem: Take the log of the function, differentiate. The only difference to an ML problem I see is that we have a prior - or would I have to approach a MAP optimization differently?  A brief sketch of my approach:

... = $\sum_{i}^n$ log$(\frac{1}{1+exp(-y_i \textbf{w}^T \textbf{x}_i)})$ + log$(\frac{1}{Z}*exp(\frac{-\sum_{i}^dw_i^4}{b})$ =

$\sum_{i}^n$ log$(1+exp(-y_i \textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_i))$+log$(\frac{1}{Z})-\frac{1}{b}*(\sum_{i}^dw_i^4)$

Log $\frac{1}{Z}$ is a constant and can be ignored, which would mean that we can derive $\sum_{i}^n$ log$(1+exp(-y_i \textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_i))$-$\frac{1}{b}*(\sum_{i}^dw_i^4)$ with respect to w.

Is this correct? Two additional questions regarding some notation: I find it confusing that the weight w is also indexed over i - as far as I understand, the index i for the weights just goes over the dimension of the feature space (and not like the index i of the datasamples over the number of datasamples n)..?
Secondly, in $P(y | \textbf{x,w}) = \frac{1}{1+exp(-y \textbf{w}^T \textbf{x})}$, as I understand $\textbf{x}$ is a n*d matrix, containing the n datasamples of dimension d - is this correct?

Comment: You don't have to approach a MAP optimization differently - the only difference is that you're maximizing the *posterior* and not the likelihood. If its the MAP for the weights you want, then you need to maximize the posterior for the weights. Notation-wise this is $P(\mathbf{w} | \mathbf{y,x},b) \propto \prod_{i}^n P(y_i | x_i , \mathbf{w})*P(\mathbf{w}|b)$.

Comment: CBowman Thx! Is my calculation in particular correct? @jibounet: This is how I understood it as well, but if $\textbf{x}$ is **one** sample, what is then $\textbf{x}_i$? I guess that here i is the i-th datasample (as in contrast to the i in w where it is the i-th feature)? Thank you

Comment: $p(y \mid \mathbf{x},\mathbf{w})$ is the generative model where $\mathbf{x}$ is _any_ sample. Now, for a dataset $(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$, each $\mathbf{x}_i$ is _a_ sample.

Comment: @jibounet Thx, then the indices i for x_i and w_i do indicate indeed different things. A last question: Do we have *one* weight vector for both classes then?